# how to use Inventory UI buttons by enums

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, enums

Ill try to explain my issue. I need to do for my school project simple 2D escape room. I've got most of the scripts ready, when I click an item he add to the inventory list, and then I can see it on my inventory bar. The problem is , I want that the buttons of the UI  Bar inventory, to know after I click the item , to know what item I've been clicking on. the way I did worked half way because he always give the key item. Ive got State Machine Interface. that inheritance to 2 more scripts (that open or close the other interactive stuff (door drawer). got KeyItems script and Interactable Script and UImanager - Singleton.
is there to it in a generic way?
this is the PlayerCast Script that I add the items I click on to the inventory, thought the button need to be here

```cs
public enum item {none , paperclip , key  }

public class PlayerCast : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;
    public List<item> inventory;
    public item activeItem;

    private void Start()
    {
        inventory = new List<item>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {

                if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Interact"))
                {
                    Interactable interactable = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Interactable>();
                    interactable.CLickMe(activeItem);
                    
                }
                else if(hit.collider.CompareTag("Key"))
                {
                     KeyItems hitItem = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<KeyItems>();
                    hitItem.PickMeUp();
                }

            }
        }

    }

    public void ButtonSelect()  //this is the generic button im trying to do
    {
        this.activeItem = item.key;
        Debug.Log("Clicked");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need event.

```
public enum ItemTypes { None , Paperclip , Key  }

[DisallowMultipleComponent]

public class Foo : MonoBehaviour {

    // Action its void delegate
    public event System.Action<ItemTypes> Selected;

    public ItemTypes ActiveItem { get; private set; }; // property

    public void ButtonSelect () {
        ActiveItem = ItemTypes.Key;
        Selected?.Invoke(ActiveItem); // invoke event
    }
}
```

---

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]

public class YourUIBar : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private Foo _foo; // link on inspector

    private void OnEnable () {
        ItemChange(Foo.ActiveItem); // setup current
        Foo.Selected += ItemChange; // subscribe to event
    }

    private void OnDisable () {
        Foo.Selected -= ItemChange;
    }

    private void ItemChange (ItemTypes item) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: First off thanks for your comments! I never used Event before, is it the only way?. I don't know what's events and how to use them? but I see you used ActiveItem = item.key, isnt it gonna be only the Paperclip? what happened if it now the Key. it didnt worked for me

Comment: Oy, item its enum. Fixed.